# batch script to get all the tables in postgres database as csv

Tags: postgresql, backup, csv

I have a remote postgresql database with a lot of schemas. I want to dump the tables that is specific schema as .CSV file for each table. I'm aware of the COPY command but I'm not sure how to write a batch script that will execute the COPY command.

Comment: give some more explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried shell script, as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
source /etc/profile
. ~/.bash_profile
time=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
 
PGPASSWORD=password psql -U public -d root -h 192.168.1.1 -p 33 -f /file/proc.sql
 
PGPASSWORD=password psql -X -A -d "public" -U "root" -h "192.168.1.1" -p "33" -F '|' -t -c "select * from tablename" >  /file/tablename_${time}.txt
```